# Python Pandas: Balance an unbalanced dataset (for panel analysis)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I know this might be easy to do. I can do it in Stata but I'm trying to move to Python.

I have a big dataset that it's unbalance. It looks like this:

[image]

And I need to get a dataset as follows:

[image]

Any guidance it's welcome. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

one way is to set 'year' as another level of index with `set_index`, `reindex` using `pd.MultiIndex.from_product` and `reset_index` the data from 'year' as a column.

Example dataframe with the same structure:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame( {'year':[2003,2004,2002,2004,2005,2006],
                    'city_code':['a']*2+['b']*4,
                    'total_tax':pd.np.random.randint(100,1000,6)},
                   index=pd.Index(data=[9]*2+[54]*4,name='id_inf'))
print(df)
       city_code  total_tax  year
id_inf                           
9              a        417  2003
9              a        950  2004
54             b        801  2002
54             b        218  2004
54             b        886  2005
54             b        855  2006
```

Now you can create the `df_balanced` with the method:

```
df_balanced = (df.set_index('year',append=True)
                 .reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.index.unique(),
                                                      range(df.year.min(),df.year.max()+1)],
                                                     names=['id_inf','year']))
                 .reset_index(level=1))
```

And you get:

```
print (df_balanced)
        year city_code  total_tax
id_inf                           
9       2002       NaN        NaN
9       2003         a      417.0
9       2004         a      950.0
9       2005       NaN        NaN
9       2006       NaN        NaN
54      2002         b      801.0
54      2003       NaN        NaN
54      2004         b      218.0
54      2005         b      886.0
54      2006         b      855.0
```

To fill the `NaN`, different methods but here two ways. For the column 'city_code', you can use `groupby` and `transform` with `max` to get the value and for the column 'total_tax', just `fillna` with 0 such as:

```
df_balanced['city_code'] = df_balanced.groupby(level=0)['city_code'].transform(max)
df_balanced['total_tax'] = df_balanced['total_tax'].fillna(0)

print (df_balanced)
        year city_code  total_tax
id_inf                           
9       2002         a        0.0
9       2003         a      417.0
9       2004         a      950.0
9       2005         a        0.0
9       2006         a        0.0
54      2002         b      801.0
54      2003         b        0.0
54      2004         b      218.0
54      2005         b      886.0
54      2006         b      855.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm just having an issue with the line: df_balanced['city_code'] = df_balanced.groupby(level=0 ['city_code'].transform(max). This is showing me this error: TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'

Comment: @PAstudilloE I would say that in your column 'city_code', for a same 'id_inf' , you have a mix rows with of only numbers some have characters in them. Anyway, try doing `df_balanced['city_code'] = df_balanced.groupby(level=0)['city_code'].ffill().bfill()`

Comment: Thanks @Ben.T 
Now I'm having an issue, when I'm trying to run this for my whole dataset, I'm getting this error. Do you know why this might be happening? AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'MultiIndex'

Answer (score 2):

Here's a slight modification of [Ben's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53439858/13708745) answer.
Whenever you're trying to create a balanced panel, I find it easiest to just use `stack`/`unstack`, rather than re-define the index:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'year':[2003, 2004, 2002, 2004, 2005, 2006],
                   'city_code':['a']*2+['b']*4,
                   'total_tax':np.random.randint(100, 1000, 6)},
                   index=pd.Index(data=[9] * 2 + [54] * 4, name='id_inf'))
# Create balanced panels with NaNs using stack/unstack
df = df.set_index('year', append=True).unstack().stack(dropna=False)
print(df)
```

This will create your balanced panel with NaNs:

```py
            city_code  total_tax
id_inf year                     
9      2002       NaN        NaN
       2003         a      110.0
       2004         a      324.0
       2005       NaN        NaN
       2006       NaN        NaN
54     2002         b      885.0
       2003       NaN        NaN
       2004         b      419.0
       2005         b      275.0
       2006         b      732.0
```

You can also use `unstack`/`stack` to apply the `fillna()` method within a column or row:

```py
# Fillna() works within columns/rows; stack and unstack appropriately to use this method
df = df.unstack('id_inf')
df['city_code'] = df['city_code'].fillna(method='ffill').fillna(method='bfill')
df = df.stack().swaplevel().sort_index()
print(df)
```

```py
            city_code  total_tax
id_inf year                     
9      2002         a        NaN
       2003         a      110.0
       2004         a      324.0
       2005         a        NaN
       2006         a        NaN
54     2002         b      885.0
       2003         b        NaN
       2004         b      419.0
       2005         b      275.0
       2006         b      732.0
```

Answer (score 1):

This way may be easier to understand and can be easily adapted to more complicated scenarios.

Let's say we have an unbalanced panel `df` and three dimensions to expand: city, year, month.

```py
import itertools

import pandas as pd

balanced_idx = pd.DataFrame(
    itertools.product(
        set(dfm['ctry_iso']),  # Dimension 1: All country codes
        range(1970, 2021),   # Dimension 2: All years
        range(1, 13)  # Dimension 3: All months
    )
    , columns=['ctry_iso', 'year', 'month']  # Assign column names
)
```

So now we have a balanced index. As you can see, **the good thing about this way is you can always have as many dimensions as you like.**

The next two steps are simply merging our data onto the balanced index and then filling in missing values.

```py
balanced_df = balanced_idx.merge(
    df, 
    on=['ctry_iso', 'year', 'month'], 
    how='left'
)

# Fill 1: Simply filled by zero.
balanced_df['var1'].fillna(0, inplace=True)

# Fill 2: Filled by last / next non-missing value.
balanced_df['var2'] = balanced_df.groupby(['ctry_iso'])['var2'].ffill().bfill()
```