# Python: Balance a dataset for regression analysis (rearranging dataset and filling blank categories)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a dataset ( df2 ) that looks as follows:

```
                            total_n
  ind_n4   year  city_code
     9     2003     a          236
           2004     a          520
    54     2002     b          167
           2004     b          997
           2005     b          476
           2006     b          742
```

Dataset example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'year':[2003,2004,2002,2004,2005,2006],
                    'city_code':['a']*2+['b']*4,
                    'total_tax':pd.np.random.randint(100,1000,6)},
                   index=pd.Index(data=[9]*2+[54]*4,name='ind_n4'))

df1 = df.set_index('year',append=True)
df2 = df1.set_index('city_code',append=True)
```

And the OUTPUT I'm looking for is a balance table that looks something like this:

```
                            total_n
  ind_n4  city_code  year  
     9        a      2002      0
                     2003     236
                     2004     520
                     2005      0
                     2006      0
              b      2002      0
                     2003      0
                     2004      0
                     2005      0
                     2006      0

    54        a      2002      0
                     2003      0
                     2004      0
                     2005      0
                     2006      0
              b      2002     167
                     2003      0
                     2004     997
                     2005     476
                     2006     742
```

To do this, I've been using this methodology, which was suggested for a fairly similar example from [Python Pandas: Balance an unbalanced dataset (for panel analysis)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53439133/python-pandas-balance-an-unbalanced-dataset-for-panel-analysis):

```
df_balanced = (df.set_index('year',append=True)
                 .reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.index.unique(),
                                                      range(df.year.min(),df.year.max()+1)],
                                                     names=['id_inf','year']))
                 .reset_index(level=1))
```

But, when I'm using this code, I'm getting a error that says: NotImplementedError: isna is not defined for MultiIndex

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
df3 = df2.swaplevel(1,2)
df3.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df3.index.levels), fill_value=0)\
   .rename_axis(df3.index.names, axis=0)
```

Output:

```
                       total_tax
ind_n4 city_code year           
9      a         2002          0
                 2003        317
                 2004        233
                 2005          0
                 2006          0
       b         2002          0
                 2003          0
                 2004          0
                 2005          0
                 2006          0
54     a         2002          0
                 2003          0
                 2004          0
                 2005          0
                 2006          0
       b         2002        956
                 2003          0
                 2004        609
                 2005        626
                 2006        811
```

Details:

- Use swaplevel, if needed, to get the index levels in the correct
  order.
- With pd.MultiIndex.from_product of the index levels, you can create
  all combinations in that hierarchical order.
- Use reindex to create the missing rows with the fill_value parameter.
- Lastly, rename index levels.

Comment: Excellent, pandas multiindex levels still elude me

Comment: @Vaishali I worked in a world of multidimensional cubes and analysis.  Multi Indexes are, in my mind, like a dimension with a hierarchy. Like Year -> Month -> Day.

Comment: @ScottBoston, one question. I already managed to get df3. How can I fill the city code and ind_n4 columns, so their values are included in every row. Thanks a lot!

Comment: So you have missing city_code like 'c' that doesn't appear in the source data?